# Android Library for a Week View Scheduler (no dates)

Tags: android, calendar

So I am developing an Android app version of our campus student portal.

So there exists a feature that shows the "schedule" of classes one student has, and it looks like this in the web app equivalent:

[image]

The problem is, I have yet to find an existing library that conforms to this feature. All I see is calendars with week views, but with exact dates. **I just need a simple scheduler with days of Sunday - Saturday, a timetable at the row headers, and no months, dates, or years shown to be exact.**

Also because the whole timetable seems to be space costly, it would be very efficient that the view instead shows a timetable for one day only, then upon scrolling left or right, it navigates to other days.

One library that came close to this was alamkanak's [Week View](https://github.com/alamkanak/Android-Week-View), there's a week view where it limits to show only one day within a viewport, but it still shows the date, which is very unnecessary.

[image]

Do you have any library suggestions that fits my feature exactly as it is? Or any workaround modification to any existing library (like the one above) that changes it to show the week view **ONLY** with no dates and only the time table.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use this xml file

   ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     android:weightSum="2"
    tools:context="com.mobilefirst.vediosurfacedemo.GridActivity">

   <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="0.3"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/gridview1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
       android:numColumns="7"
       android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

      <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/gridview2"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
       android:background="@null"
       android:choiceMode="multipleChoiceModal"
       android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
       android:numColumns="7"
       android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
      </LinearLayout>


     <LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="1.6"
   android:orientation="vertical">


   <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/gridview"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="50dp"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
       android:numColumns="1"
       android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

   <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/gridview3"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
       android:background="@null"
       android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
       android:numColumns="1"
       android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

        </LinearLayout>
      </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. For `gridview2` and `gridview3` use same layout file. This will give you same look as web app.
3. Set  `gridview1` to `Weekdays ArrayAdapter.`

Comment: Sorry, I can't seem to view it in Design . . . . . it also says an error "Multiple root tags" thus I can't also see its output when running the app. Could you give me a link or something that shows the layout to that?